# Webshare API Javascipt: Preview shared image

Tags: javascript, image, mobile, navigator, web-share

I have the following Codepen: https://codepen.io/Jsbbvk/pen/vYeRBZy

```
const onClick = async () => {
  const blob = await (await fetch("https://source.unsplash.com/random")).blob()
  const file = new File([blob], 'img', {type: blob.type})
  navigator.share({title: 'image', text: 'image', files: [file]})
}

document.getElementById("share").addEventListener("click", onClick)
```

On mobile, this is what it looks like when you press the button [image: image sharing]

There is no preview of the image before sharing it. Below is the intended result (which was achieved by long-pressing a random image and pressing "share") [image: intended]
Is there a way to achieve this image preview?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with a [demo](https://nifty-spicy-lamp.glitch.me/) and come to the conclusion that this seems to be a limitation in Safari. It works fine with image preview in Android.

What I don't get is why it works in [another demo](https://tomayac.github.io/fugu-greetings/public/) (click the *Share* button and you see a preview), but not in the demo above. In *Share 4* I tried to exactly reproduce what [my code does](https://github.com/tomayac/fugu-greetings/blob/main/public/js/share.mjs), but it doesn't seem to work.

It may just be a WebKit bug, I honestly don't know what's wrong and different between the two demos.